# Web designer for VS.NET ReportViewer

Tags: report, reportviewer, designer, rdl

Is there any designer for rdl files (visual studio .net reports) that can be used on a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that I've seen is RsInteract: http://www.rsinteract.com/